# how to test Independent dataset in weka?

Tags: weka

I have two datasets i.e. One is Benchmark dataset and second is Independent dataset. I tested Benchmark dataset using 10-fold cross validation in weka. Can we test Independent dataset in weka?

Comment: What do you mean by saying independent dataset? Do you want to train a model on your benchmark dataset and evaluate it on another one? Try to be more clear

Comment: @AndreyF: Yes, I want to train a model on  benchmark dataset and evaluate it on another one in weka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Weka GUI:

In Weka explorer - first load your benchmark dataset in the `Preprocess` tab (use the `open file...` button). Then go to the `Classify` tab and there under the test options select `Supplied test set` press `Set...` and then `open file...` and `close`.

Finally, select the algorithm you want and press `Start`.

Notice that the train and test files must have the same structure.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyF